# Pairplot with long variable names

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have long variable names in my pandas dataframe. It is not really possible to shorten them, for example 'Molecular mass weighted exposed area'. As you can see in the image below, seaborn generated a pairplot with axis labels that are not readable. What is a good solution to improve the readability?

[image]

I don't have to use seaborn, but would prefer its simplicity where I can just pass my dataframe as an argument.

Thank you.

Comment: Somehow you would need to know for yourself how you want it to look like, right? One could then help you achieve the desired result.

Comment: Hi Zawa, can you please add some sample data / df and your code to plot the graph to see what can be done to answer your question.